# Issues while creating response html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Created a html table with Fixed left column.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style= "width:50%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/4XG7T/3/

The table is displaying as below on Mobile device and also it is not scrolling with fixed column.

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARV8M.jpg)

Could anyone please suggest me how to achieve the expected behavior on Mobile device ?.

Comment: have you tried the "overflow:scroll" style? and since you are using absolute positioning why don't I see any alignment in your style "top/left/..."? what is your expected behavior on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice table view on mobile device is not supported by bootstrap, you need to handle it by yourself to present the data.

You need to chose a mechanism that best suits you to solve this issue, below are some links and ideas that provide solutions to this problem:

- jQuery Mobile : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/tables/table-reflow.html
- CSS Tricks : https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/
- You can also minimize the number of columns viewed on mobile in a way they can fit and provide a button "view all" per each row for the user to view all the row data in an accordion style division

**Or just keep the table scroll...**